# Which url data should add in ajax data using restapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, face-api, azure-rest-api

I am using Microsoft cognitive service face-api and I have done detecting face and I have got face ids. For detecting face, I used an image form online and add urls in request body of the rest api. Now for verifying faces, i used two images and I have two urls. So I got a problem with sending request body.I don't know which data should send in request body

```
$(function() {
    var params = {
      {
            "faceId1": "c5c24a82-6845-4031-9d5d-978df9175426",
            "faceId2": "815df99c-598f-4926-930a-a734b3fd651c"
      }

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data:"{}";
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Face API for Verify](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a) shows how to form the body of the request, depending if you want **face to face** verification or **face to person** verification. The face to `Person` would be images that are compared to other images found in a `Person` object (one you may have created previously).

The REST details of the Face API are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face

The body must have the face IDs while the parameters are optional. So, you could technically remove the `$.param(params)` and have your `data` in the request body look like this:

```
data:
"{
  "faceId1": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "faceId2": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}"
```